# How can I remove parts of string based on other column in R?

Tags: r, string, gsub

I want to remove a part of a string (based on another column) and I am interested in the remainder of the string...

Example:

```
  dt <- data.frame(SomeText = c("ABCDEF", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEF"), 
                   ToRemove = c("A", "CDE", ""), 
                   WantedResult = c("BCDEF", "ABF", "ABCDEF"))

>   dt
  SomeText ToRemove WantedResult
1   ABCDEF        A        BCDEF
2   ABCDEF      CDE          ABF
3   ABCDEF                ABCDEF
```

Thus (line 2 as example), remove 'CDE' from 'ABCDEF' so we are left with 'ABF'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace empty patterns with `^$`

```
dt$ToRemove[dt$ToRemove == ''] <- '^$'
```

and then use `stringr::str_remove` which is vectorised.

```
dt$result <- stringr::str_remove(dt$SomeText, dt$ToRemove)
dt
#  SomeText ToRemove result
#1   ABCDEF        A  BCDEF
#2   ABCDEF      CDE    ABF
#3   ABCDEF       ^$ ABCDEF
```